# How to make Wordpress in subdirectory of Next JS app

Tags: php, wordpress, next.js

Hello dear community,

I have my web app using next JS under domain name   domain.com

Now I want to have a wordpress blog (wordblog.com/community) under example.com/community

Using Next JS Rewrites, i added this to my next config :

```
async rewrites() {
    return {
      fallback: [
        {
          source: "/community/:path*",
          destination: `https://wordblog.com/community/:path*`,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
```

in my wordpress installation folder.

1- Added this to .htacces

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

2- Added this to wp-config.php :

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://wordblog.com/community');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/community');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.example.com');
```

3- Added this wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php

```
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
add_filter('rest_url', 'serve_rest_url_on_wp_subdomain');
function serve_rest_url_on_wp_subdomain ($url) {
  return str_replace('https://example.com/community', 'https://wordblog.com/community', $url);
}
```

But when i go to domain.com/community, it redirects me to wordblog.com/community.

Also some pages of wordblog.com/community are rendered under wordblog.com/community/pageX and not as domain.com/community/pageX

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this using the Alias directive in your apache setup: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

This would mean you would have to remove the redirect in nextJS. Apache will know to serve /community from your wordpress installation.